# DISCUSSION - Optimization

Tags: calculus, optimization

I just learnt the first and second derivative test .

Being a curious student , I want to know more about how does it applies to objects that we see Everyday.

topic of discussion -> Volume of Cans .

I asked myself - are the volume of cans optimised in stores ? 
I found that Each can is made of fixed amount of material . If you can melt / change the material , am I able to make a different sized container which can hold an ever greater volume ?

Optimised volume = Volume of Can / Maximum volume of Can .

What does it mean by optimised volume ?
And does it mean higher the better ?

How do I find the maximum volume of the Can ?

Does this involve me to use the first derivative and second derivative test ?

And I'm doing an experiment on it too.. I do not want to use the normal cylinder shape can .

What kind of funny shape do you think is good ?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look up Nonlinear Programming and Calculus of Variations. Both of these subjects deal with problems like yours. Basically you want to minimize or maximize some quantity (Volume) under some constraints (amount of material used, or surface area).

Also it may be easier to first think about the two-dimensional case: maximizing the area subject to a fixed perimeter. This is actually a fairly famous standard Calculus of Variations problem called the Isoperimetric problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use Lagrange multipliers to optimizing by holding the area (amount of material) constant and maximizing the volume.
So area $A=2\pi r(r+h)$ and volume $V=\pi r^2 h$. Then maximize $V(r,h)+\lambda A(r,h)$ where $\lambda$ is the Lagrange multiplier, by differentiating with respect to $r$ and $h$.
After a little algebra this gives the optimum at the height of the can being equal to the diameter. This sounds reasonable as the optimum shape would be a sphere but they roll off the shelves.
Interestingly this is not the proportions of most cans so the commercial optimisation must include other factors like ease of handling and visual aesthetics.